# How to properly use databases in Android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, emulation, adapter

I'm building an app that relies heavily on database usage. However, my emulator is behaving erratically and I can't find any pattern to what/when works and what/when it doesn't.

Below you have my Adapter and Helper class taken straight from an example I found on the web. In this form, it functions perfectly, it adds records, deletes them, updates them and displays them in a list flawlessly.

If I try and change ANYTHING (for example the KEY_TITLE value), the app crashes, even if I create a completely new emulator. I'm completely stumped by this and any help would be greatly welcomed...

```
public class PirelliDBAdapter {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="data";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="reminders";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

public static final String KEY_TITLE="title";
public static final String KEY_BODY="body";

public static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";

public static final String KEY_DATE_TIME="date_time_value";
public static final String KEY_ROW_ID="_id";

private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( "+
                KEY_ROW_ID+ " integer primary key autoincrement, "+
                KEY_TITLE+ " text not null, "+
                KEY_BODY+" text not null, "+
                KEY_DATE_TIME+ " text not null);";

private Context mContext;

public PirelliDBAdapter(Context c){
    mContext=c;
}


// database open/close actions
public PirelliDBAdapter open() throws android.database.SQLException{
    mDbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
    db=mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    mDbHelper.close();
}

// database CRUD operation
public long createReminder(String title, String body, String dateTime){
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, dateTime);

    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

}

public boolean deleteReminder(long rowId){
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROW_ID+" = "+rowId,null) >0;
}

public Cursor fetchAllReminders(){
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,new String [] {KEY_ROW_ID,KEY_TITLE,KEY_BODY,KEY_DATE_TIME}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

public Cursor fetchReminder(long rowId) throws SQLException{
    Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String []{KEY_ROW_ID,KEY_TITLE,KEY_BODY,KEY_DATE_TIME}, KEY_ROW_ID+" = "+rowId, null,null,null,null,null);

    if(c!=null){
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

public boolean updateReminder(long rowId, String title, String body, String dateTime){
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    args.put(KEY_BODY, body);
    args.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, dateTime);

    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROW_ID+" = "+rowId, null)>0;
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public DatabaseHelper(Context c){
        // create the current database
        super(c,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    //  overrides

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // create the database table
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

    }
}
```

Here's my error log when trying to add another field to the database (AFTER creating an entirely new AVD):

```
    12-28 22:02:11.806: E/SQLiteDatabase(421):  at  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:149)
    12-28 22:02:11.806: E/SQLiteDatabase(421):  at pirelli.app.dbadapter.PirelliDBAdapter.open(PirelliDBAdapter.java:44)
    12-28 22:02:11.806: E/SQLiteDatabase(421):  at pirelli.app.AdminSpinnerScreen.onCreate(AdminSpinnerScreen.java:329)
    12-28 22:02:11.806: E/SQLiteDatabase(421):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
    12-28 22:02:11.806: E/SQLiteDatabase(421):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
    12-28 22:02:11.806: E/SQLiteDatabase(421):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
    12-28 22:02:11.806: E/SQLiteDatabase(421):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    12-28 22:02:11.806: E/SQLiteDatabase(421):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
    12-28 22:02:11.806: E/SQLiteDatabase(421):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
    12-28 22:02:11.806: E/SQLiteDatabase(421):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    12-28 22:02:11.806: E/SQLiteDatabase(421):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
    12-28 22:02:11.806: E/SQLiteDatabase(421):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
    12-28 22:02:11.806: E/SQLiteDatabase(421):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-28 22:02:11.806: E/SQLiteDatabase(421):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    12-28 22:02:11.806: E/SQLiteDatabase(421):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
    12-28 22:02:11.806: E/SQLiteDatabase(421):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
    12-28 22:02:11.806: E/SQLiteDatabase(421):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If you don't paste the log of the crash we cannot be of any help.

Comment: I've added the error log above.

Comment: the log seems incomplete, you miss some lines at the beginning. which type of exception has been thrown ? please post the complete error, from the beginning (it starts with the type of exception)

Comment: I reposted the error log. Hopefully I didn't miss anything now...

Comment: your post is unchanged even though it appears edited 1 min ago. post a larger portion of the log on a pastebin such as pastebin.com and post the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the adapter class so whenever I make a change to the database, I use the commented lines below:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context c){
        // create the current database
        super(c,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        try{//USE THESE WHEN CHANGING DB STRUCTURE
            //db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            //db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        } catch( Exception E ){
            Log.v("ERRRRRRROR", E.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you perhaps installing over a previous install on the emulator? The database is only created once. After that, if you change a column name, it would not work.

If you make a change to your database structure, you need to either clear the app from the device/emulator to force a fresh install or increment the version number. Of course, if you update the version number, you need to implement `onUpgrade` to destroy the database and recreate (or do the appropriate migrations).

Comment: I'm creating a new AVD for every change and it still crashes... Is there any way to completely drop the database if it exists prior to doing anything else maybe...?

Comment: You can go the databases folder of your app and delete it manually for instance through file explorer.

Comment: so there's no way to do this programmatically...?

Comment: You can also running `adb -e uninstall com.your.application` in a terminal to remove the app from the emulator (assuming you have set up terminal to use the Android Device Bridge). What you changing title TO exactly?

Comment: You could just search for your database and remove the physical file before accessing your database helper. You could also increment the version number and destroy the database during `onUpgrade` using something like `db.execSQL("drop table " + DATABASE_TABLE);' and then recreating the table.

Comment: @Chase I'm changing the "title" to "title1" for instance, for testing purposes. The eventual goal is to add about 7 more fields to the table.

Comment: It still crashes. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I incremented the DB Version from 1 to 2 and edited the code above to include what I added into the onUpdate() method.